# Blow up for certain classes of distributions

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, sobolev-spaces, schwartz-distributions

Let $\mathbb D$ be the open unit disc centered at the origin and let $u \in H^{-N}(\mathbb D)$ be a distribution for some natural number $N>0$. Suppose that $$u|_{\mathbb D\setminus \{0\}} \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb D\setminus \{0\}).$$
What is the least $k\in \mathbb N$ such that
$$ \int_{\mathbb D\setminus \{0\}} |x|^{2k}|u|^2\,dx <\infty,$$
for any such distribution $u$? ($k$ should depend on $N$).